# CSS3. VueJS. Dynamic Transitioning Background Gradients

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions, nuxt.js

Now I change the gradient based on some logic in the application.

```
<template>
  <div :style="`background-image: ${backgroundImage}`" class="background">
    <snackbar />
    <nuxt />
    <default-footer />
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
.background {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 95%, #ffa400, #fd6e6a);
}
</style>
```

But I need to get the gradient changed gradually from one combination of two colors to another.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: you want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ejEzy/2/  ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about it

```
<div id="app"></div>

#app {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 95%, #ffa400ff 0%, #fd6e00ff 33.3333%, black 60%, black 100%);
  background-size: 100% 300%;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}
#app:hover {
  background-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

Or two layers of background

```
<div id="app"></div>

#app {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffa400ff 0%, #ffa400ff 50%, #ffa40000 100%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 95%, #ffa400ff, #fd6e00ff);
  background-size: 100% 200%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0 200%, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}
#app:hover {
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
}
```

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body,ul,li{
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        .flip-list-enter-active, .flip-list-leave-active {
            transition: all 1s;
        }
        .flip-list-enter, .flip-list-leave-active {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .demo {
          position: relative;
          height: 100%;
        }
        .demo > ul {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
        .demo .bg-color-li {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .demo .bg-color-li div {
          height: 100%
        }
        .content {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          text-shadow: 0 0 3px #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app" class="demo">
    <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
        <li v-for="curColor in curColors" v-bind:key="curColor" class="bg-color-li">
            <div :style="`background-image: ${curColor}`"></div>
        </li>
    </transition-group>
    <div class="content">
      content...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          curColors: [],
          colors: [
              'linear-gradient(45deg, blue, black)',
              'linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange)',
              'linear-gradient(45deg, pink, purple)',
              'linear-gradient(45deg, green, brown)'
          ],
          index: 0
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.curColors = [this.colors[0]];
            this.startChange();
        },
        methods: {
            startChange () {
                setInterval(() => {
                    if (this.index < this.colors.length - 1) {
                      this.index++
                    } else {
                      this.index = 0
                    }
                    this.curColors.splice(0, 1, this.colors[this.index]);
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works if I place the cursor on the screen, but I need to to change the color dynamically. I need to when I changed the variable `backgroundImage` there was a gradual change of color backgrounds.

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know, CSS cannot dynamically transition between background images unless color values are calculated.You can use the transition-group component of vue.Code reference above

Answer (score 0):

I've done that by creating a computer property that returns the style that you need, by creating a string with it. In the template you use that property on the style of the component, and that's it!

```
<v-card-title primary-title :style="productStyle">
  <h3 class="headline text-capitalize word-break-none mb-0">{{title.toLowerCase()}}</h3>
</v-card-title>

computed: {
    productStyle () {
      return 'background-image:linear-gradient(to top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%)'
    }
  }
```

Like that you can build your style with whatever logic you want and return it. Remember that a computer property always is calculated when one of its dependencies gets updated, so you'll get that style updated right away!